# Unmet Dependencies issue, not able to install/remove anything

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

whenever I try to install , or remove any package , this error shows.I used apt install -f , I have removed broken packages from recoveruy mode . How could I fixx it.

```
sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 codeblocks-contrib : Depends: libboost-system1.67.0 but it is not installed
                      Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
                      Depends: libwxsmithlib0 (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is installed
                      Depends: codeblocks (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is installed
                      Recommends: valgrind but it is not installed
                      Recommends: cppcheck but it is not installed
                      Recommends: cscope but it is not installed
                      Recommends: cccc but it is not installed
 codeblocks-dev : Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 20.03) but 20.03-3 is installed
 codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 : Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy codeblocks-contrib codeblocks-dev gcc` to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method as a last resort if nothing works -

1. $ sudo apt-get update
2. $ sudo apt-get upgrade

The second command will output the **package-name** having unmet dependencies followed by their required packages.

Start removing those packages one by one using below command-

3. $sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends **package-name**

Note - that command 3 could also output more packages with unmet dependencies since you  have removed **package-name** . Hence you would have to remove them also using command 3.

After doing this process recursively you may find that there are no more packages having unmet dependencies and then you would be able to run apt-get upgrade command.

For your case try replacing **package-name** in command 3 with following one by one-

$sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends codeblocks-contrib

it could output some more packages having unmet dependencies . So you would have to run command 3 for them too recursively.

Do the same for codeblocks-dev and codeblocks-libwxcontrib0.